# WVD outlook prompts for unlicensed/ non-commercial product

Tags: azure, wvd

We are delivering outlook, word and excel as remote apps to our users, however whenever the users launch the remote application they are being prompted to recreate profile, suggesting it can't find the previous days OST file.

the prompt states "sign in to set up office", however if you go through the sign-in process, you are confronted with the same the next morning.

We are running Windows 10 multi-session with Office Pro-Plus.

I've confirmed the image is correct and the reg keys are for the shared computer setting. As outlined in the doc below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/troubleshoot-shared-computer-activation

Is there something I've missed?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to Reset Microsoft 365 Apps for an enterprise activation state please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/activation/reset-office-365-proplus-activation-state#step-2-remove-cached-identities-in-hkcu-registry to Clear Office credentials and activation state for managed devices

I have summarized the required code for you below, but you have to download the vbs files for link above 1st:

```
taskkill /IM WinWord.exe /F
taskkill /IM Excel.exe /F
taskkill /IM Outlook.exe /F
taskkill /IM PowerPoint.exe /F
taskkill /IM Lync.exe /F
taskkill /IM MSACCESS.EXE /F
taskkill /IM Teams.exe /F
taskkill /IM MSPub.exe /F
taskkill /IM OneNote.exe /F
taskkill /IM OneNoteM.exe /F
taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /F
taskkill /IM OfficeClickToRun.exe /F
taskkill /IM OneDrive.exe /F
cscript 1-HKLM-O365-no-prompt.vbs
cscript OLicenseCleanup.vbs
del /F /Q %localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Licensing\
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity /f
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Registration /f
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity /v EnableADAL /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity /v DisableADALatopWAMOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

Answer (score 0):

I come across this issue all the time at work, especially when users switch devices.  It seems that sometimes Windows retains Office license info and when a new user tries to activate it doesnt update.  Its relatively easy to fix and this site has a quick guide on how to remove the old license info

http://itwalkthroughs.com/knowledge-base/office-apps-show-unlicensed-product/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.